# Can I do the union operator for two hashes and keep the max value

Tags: ruby, hash

I wonder is there efficient way to get my goal in Ruby.

Keep all the keys in the two hashed, and keep the larger value.

## input

```
h1 = {
 a: 0,
 b: 1,
 c: 2
}

h2 = {
  a: 7,
  c: 9
}
```

## output

```
{
  a: 7,
  b: 1,
  c: 9  
}
```

Comment: This might not be the best example - all of the values in the second hash are larger.

Answer (score 3):

[`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-merge) can take a block:

```
h1.merge(h2) {|key, old, new| old > new ? old : new}
# => {:a=>7, :b=>1, :c=>9}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) can take block. You can use it to get `max` value:

```
h1.merge(h2) { |key, v1, v2| [v1, v2].max }
# => {:a=>7, :b=>1, :c=>9}
```

Comment: You could also write `h1.merge(h2) { |_, *vs| vs.max }`